# Android shared element transition, wrong starting position

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I have a layout like the one in the picture below

[image]

where an orange frame is a `HostFragment` is built like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginStart="68dp"
                />

            <de.halfbit.audiopie.ui.common.views.SlidingTabs
                android:id="@id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:slidingTabsIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
                />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and a blue frame is a child `ItemsFragment` with a `RecyclerView` in it.

When I click on a tile in the `RecyclerView` I replace `HostFragment` with another `ContentFragment` fragment, which suppose to share clicked image. I do it by applying a shared element transition as following:

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = ContentFragment.newInstance();

AutoTransition autoTransition = new AutoTransition();
autoTransition.setDuration(3000);
fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(autoTransition);

fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.library, fragment)
    .addSharedElement(view, "cover")
    .commit();
```

It works fine beside one thing: initial position of the cover tile when animation starts in the ContentFragment is wrong ([see this screen cast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaxHAHmCsF0)) - it has undesired bottom offset.

Visually this offset looks equal to the height of the tabs bar of `HostFragment`. Do you guys have any idea of how to avoid this offset?

It's also worth to mention, that all `RecyclerView's` children have unique `transitionNames`.

Comment: Have you tried isolating the issue, to see if it's caused by `CoordinatorLayout`? It's a buggy class, so I'd try running the animation in a simple `FrameLayout` parent, and seeing if the issue is still present.

Comment: @PaulBurke Thanks for looking into it. I am kinda upset by amount of issues in latest support and design libraries. So I decided to use another kind of animation for now. I need some time to calm down and then I will try to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient but I've been fighting with a similar issue to this.

In the end all I had to do is change the android:clipChildren flag in the parent views xml to false.